# Unable to pass a payload (JSON) from Team Foundation Server (TFS) to AWS Lambda function

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, tfs, aws-lambda

We are trying to pass JSON data from TFS to AWS lambda function (myLambdaFunc). For this we are using the 'Invoke Lambda function' utility in the release definition. There is an option to pass the a payload in form of JSON from that utility in TFS.

The lambda function (myLambdaFunc) is capable to read JSON passed to it and create an entry in dynamo DB. And it is working fine if we run the function from AWS console.

But if we run the TFS release job, it is saying that the lambda function has been executed successfully, but no entry in dynamo DB is getting created. Seems like the payload/JSON is not being properly passed to the lambda function.

We are using online TFS:
https://xxxxxxxxxx.visualstudio.com/_projects

Please help!!

Comment: Could it be the case that the payload passed from TFS is a different format to what your lambda function expects?

Comment: Are you talking about [Invoking the Lambda function](https://aws.amazon.com/cn/blogs/developer/working-with-lambda-functions-and-visual-studio-team-services/) task. This task invokes a previously deployed Lambda function. Did your previously Lambda  function deployed successfully?

Comment: Yan..We are passing the  same JSON payload from TFS that we tested in AWS console.

We tried with the below JSON:
"{ "relNum": "Rel-1", "env": "dev"}"
and
"{ \"relNum\": \"Rel-1\", \"env\": \"dev\"}"

Answer (score 0):

I had to parse the event in order to access the TFS payload information:

var data = JSON.parse(event);
console.log('Message:', data['KeyX']);